# WordPress database error Duplicate entry `wp_xmlrpc_posts`

Tags: wordpress

I am seeing a lot of these errors all going into the same table `wp_xmlrpc_posts`.  I don't think I can make this increment because the post id's need to match the blog post id.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
[Fri Mar 21 10:58:40 2014] [warn] [client 216.70.110.80] 

mod_fcgid: 

stderr: 

WordPress database error Duplicate entry 

'http://hedua.com/blog/-11160' for key 'PRIMARY' for query 

INSERT INTO `wp_xmlrpc_posts` (`post_id`,`post_title`,`link`,`post_excerpt`,`post_thumbnail`,`post_date`,`post_authors`,`post_custom_cats`,`post_categories`,`modified_ts_gmt`,`blog`) 
VALUES 
(
11160,
'The Challenge of Homeschool Togetherness',
'Link Removed',
'Homeschooling families ',
'FAITH & FAMILY,Family,Parenting',
'943920000',
'link removed'
 ) 

 made by do_action_ref_array, 
 call_user_func_array, 
 heduaMultisite_import_posts, 
 heduaMultisite_import_posts_one
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a relationship between two different wp_post tables? If so, you can't really do it this way (or shouldn't).

The post_id of the wp_xmlrpc_posts should just remain the primary key of that table and don't depend on it being in synch with your post_id of the other install.

Instead, create a relationship between the two tables. You could either add a new column to the  wp_xmlrpc_posts table call something like blog_post_id or, better yet, create a lookup table that stores the relationships so that you don't mess with the core framework table schema.

Your relationship or lookup table would store the connections:
wp_xmlrpc_post_relationships with two columns: post_id and blog_post_id